# If $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is compact, then it is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

We say that $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is **compact** if for every open cover there exists a finite subcover.

We say that $K\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is **bounded** if there exists $M>0$ such that for all $z\in K,$ $|z|\leq M.$

---

> Question: Show that if $K$ is compact, then $K$ is bounded.

My attempt:

We can assume that $K$ is nonempty. 
Otherwise, let $M=1$ and we are done.

Let $x\in K.$
Consider the collection 
$$ \mathcal{O} = \{ (x-r,x+r): r>0 \}.
$$
Clearly $\mathcal{O}$ is an open cover for $K.$
By compactness of $K$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that 
$$K \subseteq \bigcup_{k=1}^N (x-r_k,x+r_k).$$
        where $r_1,...,r_N\in \mathbb{R}_+.$ 
        Let 
$$M =|x| + \max_{1\leq k\leq N} r_k.$$
        Clearly $M>0.$
        Note that for every $z\in K,$ we have 
$$|z-x| < r_k$$ for some $1\leq k\leq N.$
        By reverse triangle inequality, we have 
$$|z| - |x| \leq |z-x| < r_k \leq M-|x|.$$
        It follows that $|z|\leq M$ for all $z\in K.$
        Hence, $K$ is bounded.

---

> My question is that can we take such $M$ in the proof above? 
>   Is it valid?

Comment: Yes that's a good proof and there is no problem with the choice of $M$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's worthwhile adding that although there is no issue in the proof, an easier method is to take the open cover $\mathcal{O} = \{(-R, R) \mid R > 0\}$.

The argument then simplifies to the following: $K$ is compact, so there is a finite subcover $$\{(-R_i, R_i) \mid i = 1, \cdots, n\}$$

If $\overline{R} = \max R_i$ then $K \subset B_{\overline{R}}(0) = (-\overline{R}, \overline{R})$, i.e. each $x \in K$ satisfies $\lvert x \rvert \leq \overline{R}$. Note it is true in general that a compact subset of a metric space is bounded (and totally bounded).

Comment: We know that $R_n$ is the biggest among all $R_i$. So the notation $\overline{R}$ is not needed.

Comment: Thanks - I'll leave the answer as it is since I did not explicitly state the $R_i$ were ordered by magnitude, but I agree its neater had I written $0 < R_1 < R_2 < \cdots < R_n$.